# Does Special Relativity Set a Canonical Zero of Energy?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, symmetry, potential-energy

In special relativity, one has the equation
$$
E^2 = m^2 + p^2
$$
It seems like this is saying that there is an absolute zero of energy: the energy of a massless, momentumless particle.

On the other hand, it's usually said in physics that the zero of energy is set arbitrarily. How are these two positions reconciled?

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of like the analogue of kinetic energy in Newtonian physics. If you add in potential energy as well, then that can have an arbitrary zero.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. So there's an absolute zero of kinetic energy, but once you throw in potentials, there's a (gauge?) symmetry.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins I would say that in a given Lorentz or Galilean frame, there is a *natural* zero of the kinetic energy (namely, particle at rest), although I suppose that you could still add an arbitrary contant if you wanted while still preserving conservation of energy. The potential energy does not always have such a natural choice of zero. However, this symmetry of shifting the potential energy by a constant is a global symmetry, not a gauge symmetry.

Comment: What do you mean by R?

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for answering my question about whether or not it was a gauge symmetry also. Only months ago I sat in on a  lecture series that was entirely concerned with explaining the difference between gauge and global symmetries, and it's already left me.